# Calculating points where a function is not invertible

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$  be the function $f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z, x^2+y^2+z^2, x^3+y^3+z^3).$

For which $a \in \mathbb{R^3}$ is $f$ not invertible?

Comment: What do you mean by invertible? Do you regard a point not in the range (such as (0,-1,0) ) as a point which is not invertible? Do you mean locally invertible? Or do you simply mean that we cannot find two distinct points with that image?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively I'd say that "the points where $f$ is not invertible" means the points where $f$ can not be locally inverted, i.e. where the implicit function theorem does not hold.

In fact, you are just looking for the points where your jacobian matrix is not invertible.

Do you know what the jacobian matrix of $f$ at the point $(x,y,z)$ is?

Comment: Yes, I think you are probably right that that is what the question is looking for.